# Vertical labeling of names in kinship2 package

Tags: r

I am using the R-Package kinship2 to plot pedigree family. I wanted to add the names in the plot so in added a variable Names to my data frame and it worked fin in the pedigree function and plotting. Now i have a large family and the names overlap.  Is it possible to rotate the names 90 degrees. I managed reducing the character size but this was not enough.

Fot the example : id2 list of names which will print horizontally.

```
library(kinship2)
###################################################
### code chunk number 11: ped2update. names
###################################################
df2 <- sample.ped[sample.ped$ped==2,]
id2 <- paste(df2$id, c("John", "Linda", "Jack", "Rachel", "Joe", "Deb", 
                     "Lucy", "Ken", "Barb", "Mike", "Matt", 
                     "Mindy", "Mark", "George"), sep="\n")
df2$censor <- c(1,1, rep(0, 12))
ped2 <- pedigree(df2$id, df2$father, df2$mother, 
             df2$sex, status=df2$censor)
plot(ped2, col=ifelse(df2$avail, 2, 1), id=id2, cex=.5)
```

### #

Any help.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try `par(srt=90)`before calling `plot.pedigree`?

Comment: Oh This works great. I used srt=90 inside the plot function.

Comment: Thanks a lot and best wishes for the new year.

Comment: @lukeA post as answer please.

Comment: Answered. Thanks